# Using RPC to send a message from a client to other clients

Tags: c, server, client, rpc

I'm trying to create a simple "chatroom" program with C on Unix, using RPC.

Currently, multiple clients can connect to a server and call on functions generated by RPCGEN. The server receives arguments and responds with a return value. The relationship is always between client and server.

How can I use RPC to have my server send a message received from one client to another?

Comment: If the server cannot make RPC calls on the clients then it follows that it can relay messages only in response to client RPC calls.  In that case, the clients will have to regularly poll the server for new messages.

Comment: Is there a way to use RPCGEN in a way that the template program generated would allow a server that can make RPC calls on all clients at once?


I thought about the second solution, where I could use a pipe system, but I hit a snag: If any client reads from the pipe, it gets all accumulated messages at every request. If I clean the pipe or keep a sentinel to not read over the same text, text will be deleted/skipped by being read from one client, preventing reading for a second client.

Comment: I think you want to provide an RPC call by which clients can request all messages since some earlier milestone -- either a timestamp or a message ID.  The server will then need to maintain all those messages up to some point, but it can reasonably choose to time them out when they are older than some threshold.  Clients are then responsible for remembering where they are in the chat stream, and for requesting only the messages since that point when they poll.

Comment: So besides that work-around (thanks for the tip by the way), there is no way to use RPCGEN to allow servers to make RPC calls on clients?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear in my first comment: ***because*** RPC does not enable the server to make calls on clients, it follows that the server can relay messages only via its responses to RPC calls by clients.  (Supposing that the clients do not set up their own, reciprocal RPC servers, for which the central server is a client).  In any event, RPC calls are directed to specific servers, so if you wanted to perform RPC calls on multiple servers then you would need to write that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per John Bollinger's very helpful last comment: "*(...) the server can relay messages only via its responses to RPC calls by clients. (...)*"

So basically no, clients cannot communicate directly with other clients. They can send and ask for information through a call to the server, and it is through those requests that it is possible to "communicate" from one client to the other.